# asp.net "network BIOS command limit has been reached" ASP.NET 2.0 + 3.5

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I'm trying to run tinyMCE texteditor in ASP.NET 2.0 + 3.5 but I get the following error in my web.config file..

An error occurred loading a configuration file: Failed to start monitoring changes to '###\Visual Studio 2005\WebSites\TinyMCE\tinymce\jscripts\tiny_mce\langs' because the network BIOS command limit has been reached. For more information on this error, please refer to Microsoft knowledge base article 810886. Hosting on a UNC share is not supported for the Windows XP Platform.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: I had this problem as well, ultimately the thing that fixed it was a hotfix that I got from our IT dept. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/911272 for more info. Looks like all it does is set the FCNMode registry key's value to 2. Have to restart once that's set of course.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same error:
Failed to start monitoring changes to ‘\xxx\yyy\zzz’ because the network BIOS command limit has been reached. For more information on this error, please refer to Microsoft knowledge base article 810886. Hosting on a UNC share is not supported for the Windows XP Platform.

At the time I had several windows of Visual Studio open. So, the simplest solution that worked for me was to close those Visual Studious and to leave open just the one I was working on.

Then the error disappeared.

Comment: Funny problem... by just restarting Visual Studio fix the issue.

Comment: This worked for me as well. I had multiple Visual Studio 2015 windows open.

Answer (score 3):

I had this very same problem and the issue was in my web.config file. I had copied over someone elses while trying to get a custom control to work and they had been running on IIS 7, while I was still on IIS 6. The following are the offending lines:

```
<system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
  <modules>
    <remove name="ScriptModule" />
    <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral />
  </modules>
  <handlers>
    <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
    <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory" />
    <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" />
    <remove name="ScriptResource" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Pretty much, just had to remove everything between the  tag. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

[This blog post](http://www.garrypassarella.co.uk/2012/03/21/network-bios-command-limit-has-been-reached-hosting-on-a-unc-share-is-not-supported-for-the-windows-xp-platform/) helped me. It walks you through a few different things to try...

> #### 1. Add Registry value
>
> Locate the following key in the syustem registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ASP.NET Add a
> DWORD FCNMode and set the value to a decimal with the value 1. Restart
> Visual Studio to ensure the new setting is found.
>
> #### 2. Add Registry value
>
> Another registry edit here. Locate the following key in the system registry
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\ASP.NET Add a
> DWORD FCNMode and set the value to a decimal with the value 2. Restart
> Visual Studio to ensure the new setting is found.
>
> #### 3. The project is stored on an internal netword
>
> Depending on how your company’s network is configured Visual Studio may store the
> project on a network drive. Moving the project to a local drive on
> your machine and trying to run it again has been known to resolve this
> issue.
>
> #### 4. MSDN Fix
>
> This comes directly from this article on MSDN; http://support.microsoft.com/kb/810886/en-us – I’ve trimmed it down a
> little. Verify that the MaxCmds and MaxMpxCt registry values are set
> to 50 or more. To do this, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Click Start, click Run, type regedit, and then click OK.
> 2. Locate and then click the following key in the registry: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\lanmanworkstation\parameters
> 3. In the right pane, double-click the MaxCmds value.
> 4. In the Value data box, verify that the value is 50 or more.
> 5. Locate and then click the following key in the registry: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\lanmanserver\parameters Note
>    Make sure that you make this change to
>    the lanmanserver\parameters registry key and not to
>    the lanmanworkstation\parameters registry key mentioned in step 2.
> 6. In the right-pane, double-click the MaxMpxCt value. Note On SMB servers that are running a version of Windows earlier than Windows
>    2000, the MaxMpxCt registry entry is named MaxMpxCount, but has the
>    same function.
> 7. In the Value data box, verify that the value is 50 or more. Note The MaxMpxCt value determines the maximum number of simultaneous,
>    active requests that the server permits from an individual client.
> 8. Quit Registry Editor.
> 9. Restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

When you are building an asp.net deployment project, you may often recieve an ASPNETCOMPILER error “The network BIOS command limit has been reached”
. As describes by Microsoft, the error occurs because of the following reasons:

This issue may occur if the client computer submits simultaneous, long-term requests against a file server that uses the Server Message
Block (SMB) protocol. An example of a long-term request is when a client computer uses the FindFirstChangeNotification function to
monitor a server share for changes.
This issue may occur if the MaxCmds registry value setting on the client is less than 50, or the MaxMpxCt registry value
setting on the server is less than 50.
To resolve this issue, verify that the MaxCmds and MaxMpxCt registry values are set to 50 or more. To do this, follow these steps:

Click Start -> Run – > “regedit”
Navigate to the following registry key:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\lanmanworkstation\parameters

Open the MaxCmds entry in the right listview.
In the Value data, enter a value of 50 or more.
Navigate to the following registry key:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\lanmanserver\parameters

Open the MaxMpxCt entry in the right listview.
In the Value data, enter a value of 50 or more.
Restart your computer for the changes to take effect.
Note The MaxCmds and MaxMpxCt registry entries are REG_DWORD decimal entries. If they do not exist on your computer, you can create them as new REG_DWORD values. The range of values for these registry entries is between 0 and 65535.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution I have found when I have gotten same error is to close all Visual Studio solutions (usually problem happens when having more that three open solutions) then re-open the one was failing and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

The registry edits mentioned in the blog post often aren't enough as we saw with win2k8 servers in our prod environment.

I made a very detailed answer to this problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20710473/705198

That answer is an accumulation of all the technet, msdn, and blog reference material I could find on the subject, and what we ended up having to do to fix the problem. Disabling Jumbo Frames (HP Server NIC problems causing another error) and SMB2+ combined with the registry edits were what ended up saving us with our high traffic IIS sites. The registry edits alone only made it so the network bios limit errors would not show up as fast under normal load.

Answer (score 0):

This error started appearing out of nowhere. Closed all the open files in Visual Studio 2012 and quit the app. Didn't see the error after that.