# Visual Studio 2012 hangs when closing a solution

Tags: visual-studio-2012, freeze

Using Visual Studio Ult 2012 v. 11.0.50727.1.

When I close a solution or Visual Studio, the program doesn't not respond for several minutes.

I've tried the solutions proposed in http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/748339/vs2012rc-hangs-on-close
(turning of auto-recover and installing hotfix http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2493869)

Visual Studio 2010 is installed next to 2012. Here we don't see the problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This particular problem was caused by Visual Studio projects referencing dlls on a (mapped) network drive. The file-server runs Windows Server 2008 and the client (where VS is running) runs Windows 7. Hence SMB 2.0 is used between the two. SMB is the protocol used for network file transfer.

Disabling SMB 2.0, reverting back to SMB 1.0, on the client fixes the problem.
http://www.petri.co.il/how-to-disable-smb-2-on-windows-vista-or-server-2008.htm

Comment: +1, excelent tip. It worked smoothly, yeah, it must be disabled only on the client, w8 in my case. Remember to run the cmd prompt as admin.

Comment: While this solves the problem, it may introduce another, more serious problem. When parts of the project are located on a network share (which is the cause of the original problem), with SMB 2.0 disabled Visual Studio would intermittently fail certain operations claiming that [a limit for network BIOS commands was reached](http://stackoverflow.com/q/806449/11683) and that hosting project on a network is not supported for Windows XP (although it's Windows 7). I had to turn SMB 2 back on because of this.