# Configuration error in ASP.NET website

Tags: c#, asp.net, error-handling, web-config

I recently started getting this error:

> **Description:** An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.
>
> **Parser Error Message:** An error occurred loading a configuration file: Failed to start monitoring changes to 'H:\2013 T1\SIT302 Project\Deliverables\Website' because the network BIOS command limit has been reached. For more information on this error, please refer to Microsoft knowledge base article 810886. Hosting on a UNC share is not supported for the Windows XP Platform.
>
> **Source Error:** [No relevant source lines]
>
> **Source File:** refers back to the web config file **Line:** 0

I have no idea why this is happening.
The following is contents of my web config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806449/asp-net-network-bios-command-limit-has-been-reached-asp-net-2-0-3-5 and here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1562274.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It seems `H:\2013 T1\SIT302 Project\Deliverables\Website` is a network path not a local path and there is a network problem between the IIS Server and the file server containing the website files. Check the network connectivity.

Users of IIS and ASP.NET often receive this error message when running a website from a network share or NAS device. Check this [LINK](http://imageresizing.net/docs/howto/avoid-network-limit) for more information and the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I made a very detailed answer to this problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20710473/705198

That answer is an accumulation of all the technet, msdn, and blog reference material I could find on the subject, and what we ended up having to do to fix the problem. Disabling Jumbo Frames (HP Server NIC problems causing another error) and SMB2+ combined with the registry edits were what ended up saving us with our high traffic IIS sites. The registry edits alone only made it so the network bios limit errors would not show up as fast under normal load.